# iteratively selecting a subset of a model by select fields in odoo 14

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-14

I have a model

I need to provide 4 select fields

The values choosen in the first select field will be used to calculate a subset of the model to show in the second select fiedl

the valued choosen in the second select field will be used to calculate a subset of the model to show in the third select field

and so on

I read returning domains from on_change methods is deprecated in odoo 14

I'm a bit confused

How am I supposed to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still use it this way, for example:

booking_date = fields.Date(string="Booking date")

```py
@api.onchange('booking_date') 
    def onchange_booking_date(self):
        if self.booking_date:
             ...
```